# Cordova + Ionic Error Build Exception: URI has an authority component

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I'm problmea when compiling my project ( apache cordova + ionic ) , he of the following error:

```
1>  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
1>      at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
1>      at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClasspathUtil.getClasspathForClass(ClasspathUtil.java:67)
1>      at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.findDistDir(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:75)
1>      at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.<init>(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:55)
1>      at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:44)
1>      at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
1>      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon.main(GradleDaemon.java:22)
1>  Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

I looked for a solution and found it to be a malformed URI more do not know how to solve , I tried to create the project in d: / in c: / visual / projects more to no avail.

Thanks id advanced

Comment: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from build errors in VS. I’m hoping to chat with folks like you who have encountered build errors and reached out to the community for troubleshooting. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. rsalva [at] Microsoft [dot] com

Comment: Did you get this working in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen issues like this one, mainly because two reasons:
1) You did not accept the Firewall exception during the first run
2) You are running Windows using Parallels with Share options activated

Do you think your case match 1) or 2) ?